# How do classes inherited from namedtuple maintain access to parent properties with a redefined __init__?

Tags: python, inheritance, namedtuple

**Minimum Reproducible Example:**

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Test(namedtuple('Test', ['a','b'])):
           def __init__(self, a, b):
                self.c = self.a + self.b
           def __str__(self):
                return self.c

print(Test('FIRST', 'SECOND'))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
FIRSTSECOND
```

I thought when an `__init__` function is defined, it overwrites the parent implementation. If that is the case, how do `self.a` and `self.b` exist with the correct values? If I forego the `a` and `b` parameters in `__init__`, I get a `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`. I need to provide the parameters, but they're not being set explicitly in `__init__` either, and I have no called to `super()`.

Comment: Because `self.a` and `self.b` are not attributes. The underlying `tuple` structure is created in `tuple.__new__`. Honestly, what you have above shouldn't be a named tuple to begin with, maybe just a dataclass if you want to avoid boilerplate? Because the above defeats the space-saving advantage of `namedtuple` entirely

Comment: I want an immutable data type with a custom defined `__str__`. I thought subclassing from `namedtuple` would be the best way to do that

Comment: `namedtuple` isn't a class, you cannot subclass from it. it is a *class factory*. `namedtuple('Test', ['a','b'])` returns a type, a `tuple` subclass. But the way you've done it here you've made your namedtuple mutable to boot! (note, it has to be, since you are doing `self.c = self.a + self.b`. Again, perhaps consider a `dataclasses.dataclass`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't think the class is fully mutable. currently the `c` attribute is mutable and the `a` and `b` attributes are still immutable. I would like `c` to also be immutable though. I'll take a look at `dataclasses.dataclass` thank you.

Comment: Right. "not fully mutable" to me still means "mutable". In any case, chasing strict immutability in Python, aside from using a basic `namedtuple` is generally not worth the effort and can practivally always be easily subverted unless you write a C-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.a` and `self.b` are set by the named tuple's `__new__` method before `__init__` is called. This is because a named tuple is immutable (aside from the ability to add additional attributes, as `Test.__init__` does), so trying to set `a` and `b` *after* the tuple is created would fail. Instead, the values are passed to `__new__` so that the values are available when the tuple is being created.

Here's an example of `__new__` being overriden to swap the `a` and `b` values.

```
class Test(namedtuple('Test', ['a','b'])):
    def __new__(cls, a, b, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, b, a, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.c = self.a + self.b

    def __str__(self):
        return self.c

print(Test('FIRST', 'SECOND'))  # outputs SECONDFIRST
```

Trying to do the same with `__init__` would fail:

```
class Test(namedtuple('Test', ['a','b'])):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = b, a
        self.c = self.a + self.b

    def __str__(self):
        return self.c

print(Test('FIRST', 'SECOND'))  # outputs SECONDFIRST
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chepner/advent-of-code-2020/tmp.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(Test('FIRST', 'SECOND'))
  File "/Users/chepner/advent-of-code-2020/tmp.py", line 5, in __init__
    self.a, self.b = b, a
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

To make `c` immutable as well (while keeping it distinct from the tuple itself), use a property.

```
class Test(namedtuple('Test', ['a','b'])):
    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.a + self.b

    def __str__(self):
        return self.c
```

Note that `c` is not visible or accessible when treating an instance of `Test` as a regular tuple:

```
>>> x = Test("First", "Second")
>>> x
Test(a='First', b='Second')
>>> len(x)
2
>>> tuple(x)
('First', 'Second')
>>> x[0]
'First'
>>> x[1]
'Second'
>>> x[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>> x.c = "foo"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: If I wanted `c` to also be immutable, would that be something i set in `__new__` and forego defining an `__init__`?

Comment: @ajoseps you would need to use `namedtuple('Test', ['a','b','c'])` then, and maybe in `__new__` just do something like `return super().__new__(cls, a, b, a+b)`

Comment: No; the type returned by `namedtuple` is a subclass of `tuple`; the attributes defined by it are "special", not because they are initialized via `__new__`, but because of how the type is defined in the first place. If you want `c` to be read-only, your best bet would be to make it a property without a setter.

Comment: (I can imagine a case where you want to distinguish between values that are part of the tuple, and values that are attributes of the tuple, even if a named tuple allows access to both using the same syntax.)

Comment: yeah I want to be able to specify an instance of the datatype with 2 parameters, and have a 3rd property be derived from the 2, but immutable. I would want to avoid explicitly specifying 3 properties in a `namedtuple` since that might lead to the third being explicitly specified.